# Python extract all substrings between character and another string

Tags: python, regex

Similar questions out there, but my use case is to extract all substrings that exist between a marker and another string that also includes a '(', which seems to be throwing off regex. Like this-

qry_text -

```
with
qry_1 as ( qry text)
, 
qry_2 as (qry text)
```

I'd like to extract all subqueries with something like extract between ' ' and 'as ('

```
re.findall(r'''(.+?)as (',qry_text)
```

To get -

```
qry_1,qry2
```

Regex is not well understood to me, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: In regex, and in strings for most programming languages, \ is an escape character. Here, `(` is understood to mean "start capturing" which you understand, so if you want to include a `(` that is not the start of a capture group, you should write `\(`.

Comment: that's helpful, thank you. And after some testing, I do see that this works for me - ```re.findall(r'' '(.+?)as \(',qry_text)```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe named groups in regex can bring you some handy features:

```
import re

input_str = """with
qry_1 as ( qry text)
,
qry_2 as (qry text)"""

for text in input_str.splitlines():
    match = re.search(r'(?P<query>^.*?) as \((?P<text>.*?)\)', text)
    if match:
        print(match.groupdict())

# {'query': 'qry_1', 'text': ' qry text'}
# {'query': 'qry_2', 'text': 'qry text'}
```